# What is the most efficient way to store and update hierarchical data for a Flex AdvancedDataGrid?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid, arraycollection

I have a Flex application that has an AdvancedDataGrid that displays hierarchical data in a tree.  I'm currently storing this data in XML and it's being updated about every second.  This was working well for a while, but the amount of data I have to store and update has increased lately and it's slowing down the application to the point that it's becoming unusable and crashing frequently.

So I need a more efficient way to store, update, and access this data.  The main requirement is that whatever I use to store the data needs to be able to be converted to a HierarchicalData object that I can use as the data provider for my AdvancedDataGrid (to enable the tree display).

I'm thinking about trying an ArrayCollection, since that's the only other type shown in the Adobe provided examples (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_06.html).  Would this be more efficient than using XML?  Is there another data type that might be even faster to access than either of these?

Comment: I wrote down a few things I found out when working with hierarchical data [here](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/search/label/HierarchicalCollectionView). You might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am performing many update or search operations on a data structure, I always convert any serial data (xml, json, etc.) to strongly typed model classes. This will allow data operations to execute as quickly as possible. The AdvancedDataGrid uses the HierarchicalData class to describe the structure, so you just need to make sure your model conforms to that structure (or create a custom descriptor).

For example:

```
public class MyBranchNode extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function MyBranchNode(data:XML, target:IEventDispatcher = null)
    {
        super(target);

        setMemento(data);
    }

    public var children:Array;

    private var _label:String;

    [Bindable(event = "labelChange")]
    public function get label():String
    {
        return _label;
    }

    public function set label(value:String):void
    {
        if(_label == value)
            return;

        _label = value;
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("labelChange"));
    }

    /**
     * Parse your XML into into binary data
     */
    private function setMemento(data:XML):void
    {
        this.label = data.label;

        for each(var child:XML in data.children())
        {
            if(this.children == null)
                this.children = [];

            this.children.push(new MyLeafNode(child));
        }
    }
}



public class MyLeafNode extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function MyLeafNode(data:XML, target:IEventDispatcher = null)
    {
        super(target);

        setMemento(data);
    }

    private var _label:String;

    [Bindable(event = "labelChange")]
    public function get label():String
    {
        return _label;
    }

    public function set label(value:String):void
    {
        if(_label == value)
            return;

        _label = value;
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("labelChange"));
    }

    /**
     * Parse your XML into into binary data
     */
    private function setMemento(data:XML):void
    {
        this.label = data.label;
    }
}
```